# What is the meaning of \$I_{B}(saturation)\$,\$I_{C}(saturation)\$, and \$V_{CE}(saturation)\$?

Tags: transistors

Is saturation here synonym to saying maximum, but \$V_{CE}\$(saturation) surely isn't the maximum, so What is the meaning of the word saturation in the above question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Saturation" does not simply mean maximum. In the context of certain amplifiers, saturation does mean maximum, but in the context of a BJT, saturation refers to a particular mode of operation, where the base-collector junction is forward biased and that junction no longer has a meaningful depletion region.

In that regard, Vce_sat is interpreted as the expected voltage across the collector and emitter when a BJT is saturated at some typical level of saturation. For example, the [PN2222A datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/p2n2222a-d.pdf) includes the following section (with many rows omitted so you can see the header next to the relevant row):

[image]

The manufacturer is essentially saying that if 150 mA is injected into the collector and 15 mA is injected into the base to place the transistor into saturation at that level of current, the expected collector-emitter voltage will be at most 0.3 V.

Depending on manufacturing variations, it could be lower for some units, but if it were higher, that transistor would not meet spec.

Answer (score 2):

Typically those numbers on a transistor datasheet refer to guaranteed specifications for a transistor when used as a switch and when 'on'. That usually means the transistor is saturated by conventional definition such as Vce < Vbe but the important thing is that the transistor is fairly heavily driving 'on' and the conditions are specified explicitly, not simply implied by 'saturation'. (There is more than one definition of 'saturation', some fairly loose, so keep that in mind).

For example, for the [2N4401](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mmbt4401-d.pdf) from Onsemi:

[image]

Vce(sat) with a collector current of 500mA will be maximum 0.75V provided you give the base 50mA. Under the same conditions Vbe will be maximum 1.2V.

If your collector current is different from 500mA or your base current is different from 50mA or the temperature is different from 25°C then nothing is guaranteed, but in practice you can estimate the worst-case numbers from the guaranteed maximums and the typical characteristics, by interpolation for example.

[image]

[image]